# Higher order function parameter

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, higher-order-functions, parse-error

Problem with and_ function

"error: Parse error in pattern: f1"

```
 type Movie = (String, Double, String)

-- movies :: [(String, Double, String)]
movies :: [Movie]
movies = [ ("Green Book", 8.3, "Peter Farrelly")
     , ("Inception", 8.8, "Christopher Nolan")
     , ("Incredibles 2", 7.7, "Brad Bird")
     , ("The Dark Knight", 9.0, "Christopher Nolan")
     ]

imdbAtLeast :: Double -> Movie -> Bool
imdbAtLeast minRank (_, rank, _)
  | rank < minRank = False
  | otherwise      = True

director :: String -> Movie -> Bool
director expDir (_, _, dir)
  | expDir == dir = True
  | otherwise     = False
```

here is the wrong function

```
and_ :: (Movie -> Bool) -> (Movie -> Bool) -> Movie -> Bool
and_ (f1 param1) (f2 param2) (_, rank, dir)
  | f1 == director = (f1 param1 dir) && (f2 param2 rank)
  | otherwise      = (f1 param1 rank) && (f2 param2 dir)
```

here is two test for and_ function

```
and_ (director "Brad Bird") (imdbAtLeast 7.5) ("Incredibles 2", 7.7, "Brad 
Bird")
and_ (imdbAtLeast 7.5) (director "Brad Bird")  ("Incredibles 2", 7.7, "Brad 
Bird")
```

Comment: Could you clarify what your intention is for the `and_` function? Is it as simple as you want it to return `True` if and only if both the functions passed to it return `True` when applied to the 3rd argument? If so, that's just `and_ f g m = f m && g m`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `and_` does not see `director` and `"Brad Bird"` directly; it gets the function that *results* from applying `director` to `"Brad Bird"` (and similarly for the second argument.

```
and_ :: (Movie -> Bool) -> (Movie -> Bool) -> Movie -> Bool
and_ f1 f2 (_, rank, dir) | ...
```

The bigger problem is that you can't compare functions for equality. Even assuming `director` itself *was* passed as a distinct argument, you can't check if it's the same function referred to by `director`.

What you want is to simply apply each of the first two functions to the third function and use `&&` on the results:

```
and_ :: (Movie -> Bool) -> (Movie -> Bool) -> Movie -> Bool
and_ f1 f2 m = f1 m && f2 m
```

`f1` and `f2` already "know" which part of the `Movie` argument they are checking against.

Comment: Note that you can also write this as simply `and_ = liftA2 (&&)` (using the `Applicative` instance for functions).

Comment: @RobinZigmond: That’s one of my favourite little utilities, defined monadically as `x <&&> y = x >>= \case True -> y; False -> pure False` so it short-circuits effects—ditto `<||>`